# Column not aligned on the bottom in a paper

Tags: spacing, two-column, revtex, layout

I am writing my first paper in overleaf, however I have one problem with the layout. If in one page I have a section title on le left column and then only text (both in the left and right columns) I end up with two columns not aligned on the bottom. If, instead, in the right column I start a second paragraph (after a blank space), then the two columns are aligned again on the bottom. I think I should adjust the spacing between the section titles, figures and so on, but how? I tried many things but do not work.

Below the packages I am using.

```
\documentclass[
 reprint,
superscriptaddress,
amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
prb,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
```

[image]

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. (Instead of adding real text, you can use `\lipsum` from  the `lipsum` package). If I use the before mentioned package and the information your already provided in your question to create a MWE, I end up with the following output, in which I can't see any misalignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sT2r.png

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just uploaded the picture. You do not get misalignment because you start new paragraphs..

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is more than two years old, and likely to be deleted, there *is* a possible answer.

Because the total content of both columns (and into the next page) is a single paragraph, there's nowhere that stretch can be applied to achieve `\flushbottom`.  (This is also a criticism of the design of the document class.)

The most reasonable fix is to apply `\enlargethispage` in one column to even out the length.  But since `\enlargethispage` isn't reliable except at a paragraph break, the only possibility is to apply a *negative* `\enlargethispage` just before the beginning of the paragraph in column 1.  The appropriate length should be able to be determined from an underfull vbox message in the log.